# Merge Sort: Heap Corruption on delete[]

Tags: c++, mergesort, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator, heap-corruption

Working on a class project in which i need to implement a Merge Sort to sort 500,000 items.
After many attempts I tried looking for source code online and found some here: http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-merge-sort/

I had to alter the code to use a dynamic array (for size). When the program runs the merge function, I create a new, dynamic array using the number of elements (or high) that are being merged. Once the function is finished sorting them and merge them into the original array, i use delete[] on the new dynamic array. This is where I get my "Heap Corruption Detected" error.

Here is the code (wall of text):

```
//Heap Sort

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void mergesort(int *a, int low, int high);
void merge(int *a, int low, int high, int mid);


int main()
{
//Start with element 1 of the array
int line_no = 0;
int num;
int array_size = 500000;
int* num_array = new int[array_size];

//Open file for input
fstream in_file("CSCI3380_final_project_dataset.txt", ios::in);

//Test for file opening
if (!in_file)
{
    cout << "Cannot open words1.txt for reading" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

//Read file
while(true)
{
    //Read one line at a time
    in_file >> num;

    //Test for eof
    if (in_file.eof())
      break;

    num_array[line_no] = num;

    //Increment array position
    line_no++;

}

//Close the file
in_file.close();

//Start Time
clock_t time_a = clock();   

//Run Sorting Algorithim
mergesort(num_array, 0, array_size-1);  

//End Time
clock_t time_b = clock();



//Elapsed Time
if (time_a == ((clock_t)-1) || time_b == ((clock_t)-1))
{
    cout << "Unable to calculate elapsed time" << endl;
}
else
{
    int total_time_ticks = time_b - time_a;
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << total_time_ticks << endl;
}

delete[] num_array; 

return 0;
}

void mergesort(int *a, int low, int high)

{

int mid;

if (low < high)

{

    mid=(low+high)/2;

    mergesort(a,low,mid);

    mergesort(a,mid+1,high);

    merge(a,low,high,mid);

}

return;

}

void merge(int *a, int low, int high, int mid)

{


//--------------------------Create new array-------------------------------

int* sort_array = new int[high];

//--------------------------New Array Created-----------------------------

int i, j, k;

i = low;

k = low;

j = mid + 1;

while (i <= mid && j <= high)

{

    if (a[i] < a[j])

    {

        sort_array[k] = a[i];

        k++;

        i++;

    }

    else

    {

        sort_array[k] = a[j];

        k++;

        j++;

    }

}

while (i <= mid)

{

    sort_array[k] = a[i];

    k++;

    i++;

}

while (j <= high)

{

    sort_array[k] = a[j];

    k++;

    j++;

}

for (i = low; i < k; i++)

{

    a[i] = sort_array[i];

}

//---------------------------Delete the New Array--------------------

delete[] sort_array;

//--------------------------Oh No! Heap Corruption!------------------

}
```

Comment: Thou'st got a crush on whitespace! :D

Comment: First rule of C++: don't do your own memory management.

Comment: I think you are accessing 1 past the end of your sort_array you created in merge. You can not access sort_array[high].

Comment: "merge sort" - is this supposed to be a top down or bottom up merge sort? While top down merge sort is a common classroom exercise, most "real world" merge sorts are bottom up. In either case, you can do a one time allocation of a second temp array, and do merge steps from one array to the other and back, the direction depends on the top down recursion level or bottom up iteration. For top down, you need two "sister" functions for the recursive part, one that ends up with data in the original array, the other that ends up with data in the temp array, each "sister" function calls the other one.

Comment: For bottom up, you consider the array of n elements to be n groups of size 1. You merge even and odd groups from one array to the other, with the direction alternating each time you complete a pass. After completing a pass (merging all elements to the "other" array), then double the size (2, 4, ... ) and swap pointers to change direction. The sort is done when group size is greater than or equal to array size.

Answer (score 2):

I'll spare you the "you should be using vectors", "you should be using smart pointers", etc. You should be, and I'll leave it at that. Regarding your actual problem....

You're writing one-past the allocated space of your array. The allocated size is `high`:

```
int* sort_array = new int[high];
```

meaning you can only dereference from `0..(high-1)`. Yet this:

```
while (j <= high)
{
    sort_array[k] = a[j];
    k++;
    j++;
}
```

is one location that is guaranteed to write to `sort_array[high]`, and therefore invoke **undefined behavior**.

---

**A Different Approach**

Mergesort is about div-2 partitioning. You know this. What you may *not* have considered is that C and C++ both perform pointer-arithmetic *beautifully* and as such you only need two parameters for `mergesort()`: a base address and a length. the rest can be taken care of for you with pointer math:

Consider this:

```
void mergesort(int *a, int len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    int mid = len/2;    
    mergesort(a, mid);
    mergesort(a + mid, len-mid);
    merge(a, mid, len);
}
```

And a `merge` implementation that looks like this:

```
void merge(int *a, int mid, int len)
{
    int *sort_array = new int[ len ];
    int i=0, j=mid, k=0;

    while (i < mid && j < len)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
            sort_array[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            sort_array[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    while (i < mid)
        sort_array[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j < len)
        sort_array[k++] = a[j++];

    for (i=0;i<len;++i)
        a[i] = sort_array[i];

    delete[] sort_array;
}
```

Invoked from `main()` like the following. Note: I've removed the file i/o in place of a random generation just to make it easier to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void mergesort(int *a, int len);
void merge(int *a, int mid, int len);

int main()
{
    std::srand((unsigned int)std::time(nullptr));

    // Start with element 1 of the array
    int array_size = 500000;
    int* num_array = new int[array_size];
    std::generate_n(num_array, array_size, std::rand);

    // Start Time
    clock_t time_a = clock();

    // Run Sorting Algorithim
    mergesort(num_array, array_size);

    // End Time
    clock_t time_b = clock();

    //Elapsed Time
    if (time_a == ((clock_t)-1) || time_b == ((clock_t)-1))
    {
        cout << "Unable to calculate elapsed time" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int total_time_ticks = time_b - time_a;
        cout << "Elapsed time: " << total_time_ticks << endl;
    }

    delete[] num_array;

    return 0;
}
```

This resulted is an elapsed time of:

```
Elapsed time: 247287
```

---

**More Efficient**

By now you've seen that you will need at most N-space in addition to you sequence. The top-most merge should e evidence enough of that. What you may *not* consider is that in-reality that is *exactly* the space you need, and you can allocate it up-front and use it throughout the algorithm if you desire. You can keep the current entrapping for `mergesort()`, but we'll be wrapping it up with a front-loader that allocates all the space we'll ever need *once*:

```
// merges the two sequences  a[0...mid-1] and a[mid...len-1]
//  using tmp[] as the temporary storage space
static void merge_s(int *a, int *tmp, int mid, int len)
{
    int i=0, j=mid, k=0;

    while (i < mid && j < len)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
            tmp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            tmp[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    while (i < mid)
        tmp[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j < len)
        tmp[k++] = a[j++];

    for (i=0;i<len;++i)
        a[i] = tmp[i];
}

static void mergesort_s(int *a, int *tmp, int len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    int mid = len/2;
    mergesort_s(a, tmp, mid);
    mergesort_s(a + mid, tmp+mid, len-mid);
    merge_s(a, tmp, mid, len);
}

void mergesort(int *a, int len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    int *tmp = new int[len];
    mergesort_s(a,tmp,len);
    delete [] tmp;

}
```

This resulted in an elapsed time of:

```
Elapsed time: 164704
```

Considerably better than we had before. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The copy step shown in WhozCraig's code example can be avoided using a pair of functions to control the direction of the merge (note - a bottom up merge would still be faster).

Note - I wouldn't recommend using either WhozCraig's or my code example, since these methods were probably not covered in your class, and it's supposed to be code written based on what you were taught in your class. I don't know if bottom up merge sort was covered in your class, so I didn't post an example of it.

```
mergesort_s(int *a, int *tmp, int len)
{
// ...
    mergesort_atoa(a, tmp, 0, len);
// ...
}

mergesort_atoa(int *a, int *tmp, int low, int end)
{
    if((end - low) < 2){
        return;
    }
    int mid = (low + end) / 2;
    mergesort_atot(a, tmp, low, mid);
    mergesort_atot(a, tmp, mid, end);
    merge_s(tmp, a, low, mid, end);
}    

mergesort_atot(int *a, int *tmp, int low, int end)
{
    if((end - low) < 2){
        tmp[0] = a[0];
        return;
    }
    int mid = (low + end) / 2;
    mergesort_atoa(a, tmp, low, mid);
    mergesort_atoa(a, tmp, mid, end);
    merge_s(a, tmp, low, mid, end);
}    

void merge_s(int *src, int *dst, int low, int mid, int end)
{
    int i = low;                    // src[] left  index
    int j = mid;                    // src[] right index
    int k = low;                    // dst[]       index
    while(1){                       // merge data
        if(src[i] <= src[j]){       // if src[i] <= src[j]
            dst[k++] = src[i++];    //   copy src[i]
            if(i < mid)             //   if not end of left run
                continue;           //     continue (back to while)
            while(j < end)          //   else copy rest of right run
                dst[k++] = src[j++];
            return;                 //     and return
        } else {                    // else src[i] > src[j]
            dst[k++] = src[j++];    //   copy src[j]
            if(j < end)             //   if not end of right run
                continue;           //     continue (back to while)
            while(i < mid)          //   else copy rest of left run
                dst[k++] = src[i++];
            return;                 //     and return
        }
    }
}
```